# Able to marshall a file but only if the method is called from within a test

Tags: java, jsf, jaxb, glassfish, marshalling

I am doing some TDD  to marshall an object into an XML file.
For some reason something is going wrong, because I can perfectly see my test green and the file perfectly be created, but when I execute the production code it doesn't work.

Let me show you this:

Have a look at the following test:

```
 private TermManager manager = new TermManagerImpl();

 @Test
    public void a_new_term_is_marshalled() {
        Term term = new Term("AAA","AAA");
        manager.add(term);
        assertThat(term.getCreationPath(),is(notNullValue()));
    }
```

So this test checks that a file exists in the project after a marshalling was done.
The class Term is just an entity annotated with JAXB that also contains a method that determines the path where the xml was created(if created):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="TERM",namespace = "com.djordje.apps.model.Term")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Term {

    @XmlElement(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
   @XmlElement(name = "CREATIONTIME")
    private long creationTime;
    //... Some other attributes

    public Term() {
     //Default constructor required by JAXB
     }


    public Term(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.voters = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    //...Get and Set methods   

    public String getCreationPath() {
        if(getCreationTime() > 0L){
            return "src/main/resources/" + getName() + getCreationTime() + ".xml";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The class TermManagerImpl is just a facade infront of the data access layer that is used to perform some validation.

```
public class TermManagerImpl implements TermManager {

    private PersistencyManager termsInMemoryStorage = new TermsInMemoryStorage();

    @Override
    public void add(Term term) {
        validateTerm(term, termsInMemoryStorage);
        termsInMemoryStorage.add(term);
    }
```

If the validation passes(I think the validation code is not relevant so I will not include it into the question), the method add() from the persistence layer is called. And this is expected to perform the marshalling. Here how it works:

```
public class TermsInMemoryStorage implements PersistencyManager {

    public void add(Term term) {
        try {
            marshall(term);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void marshall(Term term) throws JAXBException, IOException {
        term.setCreationTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        File file = new File(term.getCreationPath());
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Term.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(term,file);
    }
}
```

So that was the implementation. When I run the test, it goes green and I see the file being created:

[image]

The file is perfectly created, I checked the content and all is there.
The problem is when instead of using the test I execute the same logic from the production code. So I have a JSF backing bean that creates that Term object based on that receives from some user interface. That Backing bean looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CreateController {

    private String termName;
    private String termDescription;

    public CreateController() {
    }

    //...Get and Set methods

    public void saveTerm() {
        TermManager termManager = new TermManagerImpl();
        termManager.add(new Term(termName,termDescription));
    }

}
```

As you can see it the saveTerm() method calls the exact same logic as the test. I think there is nothing wrong with this part, I followed with the debugger and I see that the object Term has its values inside properly set. This backing bean is called from the view(I think I don't need to paste the view code)here is how the input looks like:

[image]

So when trying to marshal I get the following JAXB exception:

```
  javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/ABCDE1384006698756.xml (No such file or directory)]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:123)
    at com.djordje.apps.dataaccess.inmemory.TermsInMemoryStorage.marshall(TermsInMemoryStorage.java:40)
    at com.djordje.apps.dataaccess.inmemory.TermsInMemoryStorage.add(TermsInMemoryStorage.java:22)
    at com.djordje.apps.utils.termmanagement.TermManagerImpl.add(TermManagerImpl.java:21)
    at com.djordje.apps.frontendcontrollers.CreateController.saveTerm(CreateController.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:818)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/ABCDE1384006698756.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:116)
    ... 49 more]]
```

I am tottaly confused. Why the test works but this doesn't? What I have to do to fix this?
I follow to the debugger until the point just before the exception occurs, and this is what I see:

[image]

There we can see that the Term is a perfectly created object, with its values...
It looks like the file for some reason does not create, this is how the file object looks like in the debugger:

[image]

The exception occurs 2 lines after when the marshall method is called.
The last thing I want to mention is that I am using Glassfish 4.
Any idea why this occurs? How should I fix it? Should I test in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question now that I discovered what it was.

When running that code from the test it worked because the app server was not running. 
When the appserver was up and running, it was not possible to write into the resources file. 
This is not permitted and I think that folder apropiate to persist those .xml documents.

I simply fixed the issue by persisting the xml to a folder outside of the app project(more convenient). Since that will be specific to the machine where the app will run, I will need to create some configuration file also to be read at the time the application is deployed.

the resources folder is better suited for css,scripts,images... but rather than this specially if you have to write to it while running.

Answer (score 0):

Your concrete problem is caused because you're using a relative path in `java.io` code, such as `java.io.File`. A relative path is relative to the so-called *Current Working Directory* (CWD). The CWD is the folder which is opened at exactly the moment the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) has started your Java program (the test is one Java program, the Eclipse IDE is another Java program and the application server is again another Java program).

When you're for example starting your Java program from Windows command prompt, then it's the current path as you see in `C:\path\to\some\folder>`. When you're starting it from inside an Eclipse workspace, then it's `C:\path\to\Eclipse\workspace\projectname`. When you're starting Tomcat from inside Eclipse, then it's `C:path\to\Tomcat\bin`.

You can find out the CWD programmatically as follows:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

Do it in both the test and the webapp. You'll see that they are different.

When you specify a relative path in `java.io` code, then it becomes relative to the CWD. I.e. when the CWD is `C:\path\to\some\folder`, then a relative path like `src/main/resources/file.ext` will effectively become `C:\path\to\some\folder\src\main\resources\file.ext`.

To solve this problem, you need to specify an **absolute** path. An absolute path starts with the drive letter explicitly specified like so `C:\path\to\src\main\resources\file.ext`, or with a leading slash like so `/src/main/resources/file.ext`, which would take it to the root of the current drive and in case of Windows thus effectively become exactly the same as `C:\src\main\resources\file.ext`.